# Working with dynamic event handler in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form where I am dynamically creating Textboxes and corresponding Comboboxes along with Combobox change event. Here is the class creating combobox event handler

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cbx As MSforms.Combobox
Private avarSplit As Variant

Sub SetCombobox(ctl As MSforms.Combobox)
  Set cbx = ctl
End Sub

Private Sub cbx_Change()
 Dim i As Integer
  If cbx.ListIndex > -1 Then
  'MsgBox "You clicked on " & cbx.Name & vbLf & "The value is " & cbx.Value
  avarSplit = Split(cbx.Name, "_")
    'DecessionOnValue
 End If
End Sub
```

And here is the code on the form which is dynamically creating textboxes and Comboboxes

```
Function AddTextBox(Frame1 As frame, numberOfColumns As Integer)

 Dim counter As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim TxtBox As MSforms.TextBox
 For counter = 1 To numberOfColumns
                                     'Forms.CommandButton.1
    Set TxtBox = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    TxtBox.Name = "tb_" + CStr(counter)
    'Bouton.Caption = "Test"
    TxtBox.Visible = True
    i = Property.TextBoxDisable(TxtBox)
    ' Defining coordinates  TextBox height is 18
    If counter = 1 Then
        TxtBox.Top = 23
    Else
        TxtBox.Top = (18 * counter) + 5 * counter
    End If
        TxtBox.Left = 50
   Next counter
End Function

Function Combobox(Frame1 As frame, numberOfColumns As Integer)

Dim counter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim CbBox As MSforms.Combobox
Dim cbx As ComboWithEvent

If pComboboxes Is Nothing Then Set pComboboxes = New Collection
   For counter = 1 To numberOfColumns
                                     'Forms.CommandButton.1
    Set CbBox = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
    CbBox.Name = "cb_" + CStr(counter)
    i = AddComboboxValues(CbBox)
  ' Defining coordinates  TextBox height is 18
    If counter = 1 Then
        CbBox.Top = 23
    Else
        CbBox.Top = (18 * counter) + 5 * counter
    End If
        CbBox.Left = 150
        Set cbx = New ComboWithEvent
        cbx.SetCombobox CbBox
        pComboboxes.Add cbx
    Next counter
    i = AddScrollBar(Frame1, counter)

End Function
```

Combobox event handler is working fine but my problem is that I dont know that how can I copy the text of textbox or enable disable the textbox according to the value selected in the dynamic combobox.

Thanks,
Jatin

Comment: You'll need to dynamically insert event handling code into each of your combo boxes.

Answer (score 0):

you'll use this for example :

Me.Controls("ControlName").Visible = True or instead of Visible you can use enable, disable etc..